# Jquery is not able to behaving expactly in fire fox

Tags: jquery, spring

I am using jquery to hit the spring controller and on basis of controller response show message to end user on login page. Here i am taking about only on login fail. I want to show message to user that login failed. I write some ajax code.

Strange this ajax code is working fine for crome browser but fail in case fire fox. Can any body tell me what i have to achieve same functionality. So it become browser independent.

ajax Code is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doAjaxPost() {  
      // get the form values
      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: $("#login-form").attr("action"),  
        success: function(response){
            $('#sign-up').html(response);
        },  
        error: function(e){  
          alert('Error: ' + e);  
        }  
      });  
        event.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

Spring Controller code is here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sign-in", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String submitCustSignInForm(@ModelAttribute("model") Person model,
            HttpSession sess) {

        String response = "";
        Person person = null;
        if (sess.getAttribute("USER_INFO") == null) {

            person = tsService.login(model);
            if (person == null) {
                response = "User name or password does not match.";
            } else {
                response = "success";
                sess.setAttribute("USER_INFO", person);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

In both cases ajax query hit the controller but in case of crome it remain at same page and display the error message. But in case of firefox it moves to another blank page and then print the message.

What i was thinking may be in firefox case "event.preventDefault();" is not able to stop action of form

html form is here:

```
<form class="aui login-form"
     method="post" id="login-form" onsubmit="doAjaxPost()">
</form>
```

Form code is little bit longer so not giving the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up a jQuery-style form submit handler with a vanilla html onsubmit().  Try changing:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

To

```
return false;
```

Alternately, you can remove the onsubmit in for form tag, bind a listener to the submit event in the form, and use event.preventDefault().